# SQLite Count() of true boolean values in GROUP

Tags: sqlite, group-by, count, boolean, max

I want to get messages from a view (it is a view because it contains messages from multiple sources) in an SQLite database. If a there are multiple messages from the same user, I want only the newest one. The view is already sorted by Date DESC.
If I use the query `SELECT *, COUNT(IsRead = false) FROM Messages GROUP BY User` I get the newest message from each user and the amount of messages for each user.
However instead of the total amount of messages, I only want the amount of unread messages (Read == false)

For the following table:

```
+-------+--------+------------+
| User  | IsRead |    Date    |
+-------+--------+------------+
| User1 | false  | 2020-01-05 |
| User2 | false  | 2020-01-04 |
| User1 | false  | 2020-01-03 |
| User3 | true   | 2020-01-02 |
| User2 | true   | 2020-01-01 |
| User3 | true   | 2020-01-01 |
+-------+--------+------------+
```

I would like to get the following result

```
+-------+--------+------------+---------+
| User  | IsRead |    Date    | notRead |
+-------+--------+------------+---------+
| User1 | false  | 2020-01-05 |       2 |
| User2 | false  | 2020-01-04 |       1 |
| User3 | true   | 2020-01-02 |       0 |
+-------+--------+------------+---------+
```

How can I achieve that? The `COUNT(IsRead = false)` part in my query is just the way I imagined it could work. I could not find anything about how to do that in sqlite.

Also: Am I correct about always getting the most recent message from each user, if the output from the view is already sorted by Date descending? That seemed to be the case in my tests but I just want to make sure that was not a fluke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SELECT/The ORDER BY clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#the_order_by_clause):

> If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an
> ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is
> undefined.

This means that even if the view is defined to return sorted rows, selecting from the view is not guaranteed to maintain that sort order.

Also, with this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(IsRead = false) FROM Messages GROUP BY User
```

even if you *get the newest message from each user*, this is **not** guaranteed, because it is not a documented feature.

So, for your question:

> Am I correct about always getting the most recent message from each
> user, if the output from the view is already sorted by Date
> descending?

the answer is no.

You can't rely on coincidental results, but you can rely on documented features.

A documented feature is the use of [Bare columns in an aggregate query](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query) which can solve your problem with a simple aggregation query:

```
SELECT User,
       IsRead,
       MAX(Date) Date,
       SUM(NOT IsRead) notRead -- sums all 0s (false) by converting them to 1s (true)
FROM Messages
GROUP BY User;
```

Or, use window functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT User,    
       FIRST_VALUE(IsRead) OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date DESC) IsRead,
       Max(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY User) Date,
       SUM(NOT IsRead) OVER (PARTITION BY User) notRead 
FROM Messages;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-sWOH_2-).

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for.
There is a small problem though. In some of the older tables (that are part of the view) I did not put 0 and 1 in the IsRead column but instead 'true' and 'false'. 
These seem to get interpreted to be 0 either way.
Is there a way I can get around finding all the places in my code, where these tables are accessed and changing it?

Comment: @NuclearVirus In SQLite `true` and `false` are aliases of 1 and 0 respectively. If you mean that you stored the strings `'true'` and `'false'` then you can update these tables with 1s an 0s.

Comment: Yes, I stored the Strings true and false. I could replace them. But in parts of my java code, these values are written and read as strings. (I did not know better back then, when I wrote that code). Those old parts of my code are really unstructured and I would need to find every part of the code that is accessing these tables. That's why I asked if there is some workaround.
I figured it out now. I just use ```SUM(NOT(IsRead OR IsRead = 'true'))``` instead of ```SUM(NOT IsRead)```

Comment: About the newest Message thing: By using ```MAX(Date)``` I will get the newest Date from all Messages from this user, but what about the other columns? In the example Table above, would I be guaranteed to get ```IsRead  = false``` for User2? In the real table there are of course more columns.

Comment: @NuclearVirus in the documentation link I provide in my answer about the bare columns it is documented that when min() or max() are used any non-aggregated column's value will be taken from the row where that min or max exists: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query

Comment: Sorry, I did not read completely through that documentation before posting that comment.